# Error while initializing airflow DB in sqlalchemy package

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, sqlalchemy, airflow

I'm getting this below error while initializing the airflow database. The versions of packages are given below:

`apache-airflow==2.6.0`

```
+ /tmp/airflow-test-env-init.sh
++ cd /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow
++ airflow db init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 5, in <module>
    from airflow.__main__ import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    settings.initialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 525, in initialize
    configure_orm()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/settings.py", line 219, in configure_orm
    engine = create_engine(SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN, connect_args=connect_args, **engine_args)
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 281, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 614, in create_engine
    dialect = dialect_cls(**dialect_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 653, in __init__
    self.executemany_mode = parse_user_argument_for_enum(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 1738, in parse_user_argument_for_enum
    raise exc.ArgumentError(f"Invalid value for '{name}': {arg!r}")
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Invalid value for 'executemany_mode': 'values'
```

Upgrading airflow from `1.10.15` to `2.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

I got this one resolved. The problem was that I was using `apache-airflow==2.6.0` which only supports `sqlalchemy>=1.4 & <2.0`.

Doing `pip install sqlalchemy==1.4.49` along with `pip install -U marshmallow-sqlalchemy` solved the problem for me.